# Is there a relation between EPSG 4326 coordinates and meters?

Tags: coordinates, java, epsg

I have information about different locations in a Java `List`. Each `location` has it's coordinates (`longitude` and `latitude`)
For example:

```
longitude = 2.37364
latitude = 42.38473
```

I need to look up using an API which bus stations are near each `location` (in a radius of 500m).

I want to know how can I relate the coordinate system with meters to filter the search.

Comment: There is an ellipsoidal relation between geodesic coordinates and meters over the ellipsoid. I do not know anything about `Java`, but you can look there: https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/java/

Comment: Geographic degrees to geodesic meters is partial differential equation, only solvable through iterative means. You *really* want to find an open-source provider for this.

Comment: For a search radius of 500m the earth is practically flat, and if you don't need *much* precision, you could scale the longitude by the lat-long aspect ratio at that latitude, then convert to approximate metres. Quick and dirty. Might get you 1m precision...

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249945/how-to-use-geometricshapefactory-in-geotools-to-create-a-circle-on-map

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481651/how-do-i-create-a-circle-with-latitude-longitude-and-radius-with-geotools/36528805

Comment: or possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311272/create-dynamic-circle-polygon-from-specific-lat-long-using-geotools

Comment: but you may need to read https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268639/jts-geometricshapefactory-generate-an-ellipse-properly